# "In Folder.php line 108: Cannot open source folder" after running core:update

Tags: update, cli

An error message without any hints on how to proceed. I'm guessing permission problem? But which folder is the source folder?

Running again in verbose mode:

```
$ php7.4 cli/joomla.php core:update -vvv
```

```
 5/8 -- Downloading update package ...
In Folder.php line 108:
                             
  [RuntimeException (-1)]    
  Cannot open source folder  
                             

Exception trace:
  at /////libraries/src/Filesystem/Folder.php:108
 Joomla\CMS\Filesystem\Folder::copy() at /////libraries/src/Console/UpdateCoreCommand.php:380
 Joomla\CMS\Console\UpdateCoreCommand->copyFileTo() at /////libraries/src/Console/UpdateCoreCommand.php:327
 Joomla\CMS\Console\UpdateCoreCommand->processUpdatePackage() at /////libraries/src/Console/UpdateCoreCommand.php:217
 Joomla\CMS\Console\UpdateCoreCommand->updateJoomlaCore() at /////libraries/src/Console/UpdateCoreCommand.php:171
 Joomla\CMS\Console\UpdateCoreCommand->doExecute() at /////libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Command/AbstractCommand.php:235
 Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand->execute() at /////libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:1181
 Joomla\Console\Application->runCommand() at /////libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:403
 Joomla\Console\Application->doExecute() at /////libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php:202
 Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication->doExecute() at /////libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:448
 Joomla\Console\Application->execute() at /////libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php:255
 Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication->execute() at /////cli/joomla.php:76
```

Running

```
$ chmod -R 777 *
```

did not fix it.

Hm maybe tmp_path issue actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting tmp_path in configuration.php to a proper location fixed it.